# Can python use vCPU's instead of cpu's

Tags: python, cpu

I've bought a vps and it has 8 vCPU's but only 1 cpu I am using concurrent.futures module so it uses multiple cpu's to run a function several times at the same time but in my vps there is only 1 cpu so it is not working as I want how can I make python to use vCPU's instead of cpu's

Comment: What of concurrent.futures are you using? There's a single-core (threads) and multi-core (processes) variant.

Comment: there is a function and cuncurrent futures allows me to use that function several times like function(arg1) function(arg2) concurrent makes this two work at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vCPU appear like "real" CPU cores to the code running in your server.

So, for using all the vCPU in parallel code, you should use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module.